# Javascript Conflict?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

[this page is working](http://tonberrytest.com/blockreveal.html)

is an example of what I want to display on the following page:

[this page is not working and I don't know why](http://www.tonberrytest.com/home-test/)

although the code is identical the results are not the same, I'm assuming that there is some form of conflict with my wordpress themes javascript. Can anyone tell me what is causing this not to work and also how to recognise problems like this in the future?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check the browser **developer** tools console for errors ...

Comment: There are **8 errors** in your second link.. hit `F12` to open browser developer tool and look into the `console` tab for more details

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that there are few errors in your site.

```
Unexpected token <
```

and the second one is map API key error.

```
Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError
```

Please check Unexpected token error and try to solve it, fix all 400 error and set map API key. might be the reason is because of this errors showing in your console.